# Python Script to Return Process with highest Memory Usage

Tags: python, memory, process

I need to create a Python Script that Returns only the Process using the most memory at that time. I am having problems with parsing the values. What I have so far:

```
import psutil

x = psutil.pids()
for i in x:
p = psutil.Process(i)
print(p.name(), p.memory_full_info())
```

This returns the full list of processes in this format:

```
 ssh-agent pfullmem(rss=339968, vms=11350016, shared=0, text=352256, lib=0, data=421888, dirty=0, uss=598016, pss=605184, swap=0)
```

I am getting value errors whenever I try to manipulate these values. I want to just return the MOST memory intensive process and perhaps the RSS or VMS value.

Comment: What kind of errors do you get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import psutil

pids = psutil.pids()
processes = map(psutil.Process, pids)
most_mem_process = max(processes, key=lambda p: p.memory_full_info().data)
```

Comment: Thank you @EyuelDK that go me most of the way there. The only thing I am still missing is the uss number that would list the amount of memory. I have gotten this far in isolating the number:     jk = psutil.Process(i).memory_percent(memtype='uss')        that will take the pid as 'i' and return the uss number.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with the `psutil` library, but if you want to filter based on the `uss` just replace `p.memory_full_info().data` with `p.memory_full_info().uss`. In the end, most_mem_process, i.e. a Process object, has all the info you need, including the `uss`

Answer (score 1):

```
import subprocess
subprocess.check_output('ps -eo pmem,cmd | sort -k 1 -nr | head -1', shell=True).decode('utf-8').replace('\n', '')
```

This command returns two things: The first one, is the percentage of memory usage of the process and the second one is the running process with highest memory usage.

Comment: Please add more information and context. What does this code do and how does this answer the user's question? If you're going to make a code-only answer, the code needs to at least be well commented.